# Jquery.html() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to alert the value of $xml.html(), but i am getting undefined. There is my code

```
var xml ='<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"><TaxPayer><PersonalInformation><FirstName>aashu</FirstName></PersonalInformation></TaxPayer></xml>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
alert(xml);
$xml.find('TaxPayer').text('shri');
alert($xml.html());
```

Comment: var xml is not valid syntax... script terminates

Comment: I have changed the variable name but it still not working, can you tell me the solution of this probem. I am editing the question

Comment: @AASHUTOSHSHRIVASTAVA: what you exaclty want to be alert ?? also check this http://jsfiddle.net/9Hd5T/

Comment: I want to alert xml file before & after changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hd5T/2/)**

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9Hd5T/3/)**

```
var xml ='<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"><TaxPayer><PersonalInformation><FirstName>aashu</FirstName></PersonalInformation></TaxPayer></xml>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
alert(xml);
alert($xml.find('xml').html());
alert($xml.find('xml').text());
```

---

```
var xml ='<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"><TaxPayer><PersonalInformation><FirstName>aashu</FirstName></PersonalInformation></TaxPayer></xml>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
alert(xml);
alert($xml.find('xml').html());
alert($xml.find('xml').text());
$xml.find('FirstName').text('satinder');

alert($xml.find('xml').html());
alert($xml.find('xml').text());
```

Comment: is only alert the actual value not modify value. I want to alert/print both the value of xml

Comment: @AASHUTOSHSHRIVASTAVA Try the 2nd fiddle demo.  There's a lot of alerts, but it does show the value changed.

Comment: @AASHUTOSHSHRIVASTAVA: check the demo 2, it clearly alert `before and after modification`, 1st time is asshu and 2nd time it alert satinder , dude check properly

Comment: Thanks Satinder. Can you help me to print both the xml file in HTML page

Comment: @AASHUTOSHSHRIVASTAVA That's not how SO works.  If you have another question then please ask another question, otherwise this page becomes a specific "how do I make MY site do what I want" page.

Comment: Archer no need. I have found the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Satinder singh, i want to save the browser output in file, can is it possible. Archer i have asked the another question for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095843/can-i-save-the-xml-content-in-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var xml =$('<XMLDocument />')
    xml.append($('<TaxPayer/>')
               .append($('<PersonalInformation/>')
                       .append($('<FirstName/>').text('aashu')))); 
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
alert(xml.html());
xml.find('TaxPayer').find('FirstName').text('shri');
alert(xml.html());
```

This may help. [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rLQqg/)

Comment: What the mean of this answer. Its not related to problem. Please delete it.

Comment: @AASHUTOSH SHRIVASTAVA What you actually want to do? When you posting a question specify your problem properly.

Comment: I want first print or alert the xml without changes & then print or alert xml with modify value.

Comment: @AASHUTOSHSHRIVASTAVA if any of the answer solves your problem, then don't forget to mark as answer. So that will help others

Comment: Yes James, I have marked it. this http://jsfiddle.net/9Hd5T/3/ exact thing what i want